# Rekognition namespaces aren't resolved in Eclipse AWS toolkit

Tags: eclipse, amazon-web-services, aws-java-sdk, aws-toolkit

In the Amazon Rekognition Developer Guide  there is a tutorial  "Create the AWS Toolkit for Eclipse Lambda Project"

It tells me to resolve namespace issues in Eclipse  by doing this :

```
 The Rekognition namespaces aren't resolved. To correct this:
• Pause your mouse over the underlined portion of the line import
com.amazonaws.services.rekognition.AmazonRekognition;.
• Choose Fix project set up... .
• Choose the latest version of the Amazon Rekognition archive.
• Choose OK to add the archive to the project
```

However I am not given an option  to choose  the latest Amazon Rekognition archive.
[No option to add archive](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6zC7f.png)

Is there another  way to load this archive  or  force the install of this archive?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to an AWS  support representive :

```
The AWS Rekognition SDK is configured in the pom.xml file which is managed by Maven. You should see something like this in your pom.xml



<dependency>
    <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
    <artifactId>aws-java-sdk-rekognition</artifactId>
</dependency>


Maven will pull this package automatically for you.
```

I didn't  change my pom directly.  I created a new  aws java project in eclipse and downloaded a bunch of  examples.  When I went back into  the problem  file  it was able to see the rekognition  archive as an option.